# Spring MVC Form backing object field names

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity, spring-3

Is it possible to specify a text input field `id` to bind a form backing object to? My form is using third-party javascript and I do not have control over the input's `id` value.

For example:

```
<input id="something_with_underscores">
```

Needs to bind to this form object:

```
public class FormObject {
    private String field1;
    // other properties
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/somewhere")
public String handlerMethod(@Valid FormObject form) {
    // do stuff with the form
}
```

I am using Velocity for the html templating and when using the #springFormInput macro it attempts to bind the `id`/`name` as `FormObject.field1`. I need to tell it to look at `something_with_underscores` for the value/binding. I know if I name `field1` as `something_With_Underscores` it would work, but it does not match with Java naming conventions.